# Creating a string interpolation in json.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my `file.json.erb` I want to create values like "`20 mg"` , `"30 mg"` , etc...

I wrote something like this but this was incorrect

```
<%=(rand() * 50).to_i %> + " mg"
```

Comment: How do you mean that what you tried "was incorrect"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `+`, you can just build strings directly. Try this:

```
 "<%=(rand() * 50).to_i %> mg"
```

Answer (score 1):

almost correct, try

```
<%= (rand() * 50).to_i.to_s  + " mg" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use String interpolation too.

```
<%= "#{(rand() * 50).to_i.to_s}  mg" %>
```